# Product of two squares in finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $g$ an element of order $n$ in $G$. Assume that $g$ is a product of two squares. Moreover, assume that $n$ and $k$ are coprime. Prove that $g^k$ is also a product of two squares in $G$.

Thanks in advance.